# TypeError at /create/ PostCreateView.post() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, django-models

Me da este error
TypeError at /create/  PostCreateView.post() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

son problemas de logica creo, pero aun soy muy novato con Django y sigo aprendiendo de ante mano Gracias por la ayuda...!!

y no se donde se encuentra

mis **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from posts.models import Post,  PostView, User
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from .forms import PostForm, UserForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def RegistUser(request):
    context = ({
        'form': UserForm()
    })
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        name = request.POST['name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']

        if password2 != password:
            messages.error(request, "las contraseñas no coinciden")
    

        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        myuser.name = name
        myuser.last_name = last_name  
        myuser.phone = phone
        myuser.is_active = True

        myuser.save()

        messages.success(request, "Tu cuenta ha sido creada exitosamente")

        


        
    return render(request, 'posts/register.html', context)

def profile(request, username=None):
    current_user = request.user
    if username and username != current_user.user.username:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        posts = user.posts.all()
    else:
        posts = current_user.posts.all()
        user = current_user

    return render(request, 'posts/profile.html', {'user': user, 'posts': posts})
    

class PostListView(ListView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        object = super().get_object(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            PostView.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user, post=object)
        return object


 
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post
    
    def post(request):
        current_user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.pk)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = PostForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.user = current_user
                post.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Post Publicado')
                return redirect('list')
        else:
            form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'social/post_create.html', {'form' : form })

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'view_type': 'create'
        })
        return context
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)



class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'view_type': 'update'
        })
        return context


class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'


    
class Search(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/post_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_queryset(self):
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
```

mis **urls.py**

```
from django import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from posts.models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from posts.views import (
    PostCreateView,
    PostListView,
    PostDeleteView,
    PostDetailView,
    PostUpdateView,
    Search,
    RegistUser,
    #post,
)


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('regist-user/', RegistUser, name="regist"),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='posts/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name='posts/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('search/', Search.as_view(), name='search'),
    path('create/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('<slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<slug>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('<slug>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),         
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static (settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static (settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

mis **models.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.shortcuts import reverse

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre de usuario', max_length=20, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre', max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='apellido', max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Direccion de correo', max_length=60)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, verbose_name='Numero de telefono')
    password = models.CharField(verbose_name='Contraseña',max_length=12)
    password2 = models.CharField(verbose_name="Confirme contraseña",max_length=12)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', "phone"]

    


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default="usuariopredeterminado.png")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Perfil de {self.user.username}'





class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Titulo")
    precio = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, verbose_name="Numero de telefono")
    content = models.TextField()
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Inserta imagen del carro")
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name="como quires que se busque tu carro? sugerencia!! usa (-) para separar por palabras")
    
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("detail", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })




    
class PostView(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

mi **post/post_list.html**
aqui deberia de mostrarse el post que creo, pero me da ese error
aun soy muy novato y estoy practicando por eso me dan ese tipo de errores ayuda..

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    {% for object in object_list  %}
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src=" {{ post.user.profile.image.url }}">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div>
                        <img src="{{ object.thumbnail.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">    
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{object.title}}</h5>
                            </a>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ object.precio|truncatechars:40 }}</p>
                            <hr/>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ object.content|truncatechars:40 }}</p>
                            <hr/>
                            <p class="cardd-text">
                                Posted {{ object.publish_date|timesince }} ago
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Gracias de ante mano si me ayudaran... Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema no es de Django, tu problema es de python en general.

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post
    
    def post(request):
        pass
```

Aquí estás definiendo una clase `PostCreateView`. y dentro estás definiendo un método `post`. Pero no estás definiendo si la función es del objeto, es de la clase o es estática.

Supongamos que tu clase es un edificio, y cada departamento es un objeto, que sea del objeto quiere decir que cada objeto tendrá su propia función (como si fuera el baño de cada departamento).

Para eso python siempre tiene que admitir mínimo un argumento en la función, el objeto mismo, que por convención se usa el nombre de `self`

`def post(self, request)`

Que sea de clase quiere decir que es de la clase y no del objeto, por lo que comparten características de la clase pero no del objeto. (por ejemplo un baño comunitario en el lobby, puedes tener tu shampoo propio en tu baño pero no en el del lobby).

para eso se usa el decorado `classmethod` y siempre acepta un elemento que es la clase, que por convención se usa `cls`

```
@classmethod
def post(cls, request)
```

Para finalizar está que sea estática, esto quiere decir que aunque esté dentro del edificio es independiente a sus cosas y bien puede funcionar afuera, pero decides guárdarlo ahí. (como una máquina que solo se guarda en el edificio).

para ella se usa `staticmethod` y no se le pasa objeto ni clase, por lo que puede quedar así como esta

```
@staticmethod
def post(request):
```

Una vez aclarado esto, puedes ver que tú estás definiendo `post` como una clase sin pasarle el argumento del objeto. De acuerdo a la documentación de Django, este debe ser del objeto. Es decir agregando esto debería funcionar.

`def post(self, request):`

Comment: Gracias @Sr1871, osea que si le agrego, el parametro self a la funcion post deberia de funcionar??